# BxSlider IE issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js, bxslider

I am facing an issue with BxSlider in IE browser where the infinite loop isn't getting triggered after the last slide and also the slider breaks by showing the slides one after the other. I am using Backbone js framework and loading the BxSlider Dynamically then to facing the same issue.

Please anyone can help me out with this issue.

```
this.bxslider = this.$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pager: isTouch ? true : false,
    infiniteLoop: true,
    hideControlOnEnd:true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
     preloadImages: 'all',
     speed: 1000
  });
```

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have checked the official examples, they all works well in IE browser, you could refer to them.

Comment: Please check now I have added the code snippet also

Comment: It has 440 open issues starting 6 years ago, I'd use a more active slider if I were you, unless you have time to submit a PR or patch it locally

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following sample code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var isTouch = true;
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            autoControls: true,
            stopAutoOnClick: true, 
            slideWidth: 600,

            pager: isTouch ? true : false,
            infiniteLoop: true,
            hideControlOnEnd: true,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            preloadImages: 'all',
            speed: 1000
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="bxslider">
    <div><img src="Images/Image1.jpg" title="Funky roots"></div>
    <div><img src="Images/Image2.jpg" title="The long and winding road"></div>
    <div><img src="Images/Image3.jpg" title="Happy trees"></div>
</div>
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Still facing the same issue. Is there anything specific to be handled at IE level which will help to achieve this ?

Comment: You could try to create a new web page to test my code, if still not working, you could try to reset the [IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings). If it works well, perhaps the issue is related to other code, please check it.